# Finding work abroad

Tags: sound-design, freelance, finding-work, networking

Hi guys

Does anyone know of any good websites or community pages for finding freelance work or making contacts in Spain?

I'll be moving there from the UK September to May. I know of sites like mandy.com but does anyone know of any others? Or have any advice?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated, my first question! :-)

Comment: I'm also intrested:) spain is an awesome country:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi,

I'm Spanish. Some webs I know:

http://bolsadetrabajoencineyafines.blogspot.com.es/

http://doncasting.com/

http://www.filmutea.com/trabajos/

http://www.quientv.es/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=22&Itemid=97

http://www.adtriboo.com/es/

I'm just curious, why are you coming here?
Things are quite bad and we are trying to get out the country (UK is a popular option).

If you have any other question, just ask.

Comment: Maybe he's following the logic that if people are leaving, then there must be more gigs available. Lol

Comment: Cheers Javier! I'll look through them today. 
Basically my partner has a teaching placement in Granada as part of her degree, and seen as though I just graduated I thought it would be nice to come over and see if I could find work. 

Comment: Ah, great. 

I live close to Granada (which is a beautiful city by the way), so now you have your first contact in the spanish sound world. What field are you planing to work on?

Comment: I've just got back from Granada actually and secured a place to stay. It is a very beautiful place, where are you based? I have a list of place to email that offer audio-visual work and audio-post places to contact, but I would also want to get involved with production sound and build up my experience (I've already worked on a feature film set) and any other sound/audio projects I can find. 

Comment: I live in Seville (2,5h drive). Look me up in Facebook and we can keep in touch.